# Draw some rectangles by table tag

Tags: html

I'm trying to create this shape with **tables**:
[image: The shape]

My html code is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercise!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This html code gets me this wrong shape:

[image: wrong shape]

But when I add a row without `colspan` and `rowspan`s, the browser shows this correct shape but with an extra row:

[image: almost correct shape]

Here is the code that creates the correct shape but with an extra row:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercise!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td colspan="1"></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

**EDIT : IE shows a big blank rectangle!!!! Also what is this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

problem is likely the borders. When you add the row with all the fields specified, it draws a border between each field for all fields, but without that row, some of the borders are not drawn, so some rows have less pixels than others

Comment: So, isn't there any way to create that shape with table tags?

Comment: Another possibility is the cellspacing/cellpadding. Try adding  `cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0` to the table line.  To make sure, you have several options: - Specify the width for each td. - REmove all the borders and instead use colors to identify fields, that way you can determine if the problem is indeed the borders

Comment: another issue I remember is having empty fields. Try adding anything between the `<td>` and `</td>` like a `&nbsp;`, a transparent one pixel image, etc. and see what happens.

Comment: change the height=100% to a fixed height like height=300.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6592/discussion-between-mahdi-and-rodolfo)

Answer (score 0):

Works wonderfully for me in WebKit. Get rid of the borders on each `tr` for sure. What browser are you using? (Also, I added a `rowspan`.)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whqVC/

Comment: I have edited my question. rowspan was missing. I am using Chrome and IE.

Comment: Chrome shows the images on my question, and IE just shows a big blank rectangle!